# What is the difference between * when it come before and after something in C

Tags: c

I'm learning `C` through [learn-c.org](https://learn-c.org) and sometimes they use the `*` operator before writing something (like specifying a data type) and other times they put the asterisk at the end. I read that `*` was the operator that de-references a variable. What is the difference in the placement of `*`?

some examples from the website:

```
void addone(int * n) {
    (*n)++;
}
```

and

```
char vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
char *pvowels = &vowels;
int i;
```

or

```
int compare(const void* left, const void* right) {
    return (*(int*)right - *(int*)left);
}
```

Comment: You might find your answer at this previous SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-pointer-declarations

Comment: @pastaleg: I don't think that's right, the question is about the difference between `*` as a type specifier and an operator.

Comment: @Mat I think you should double check. Its clearly about pointers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487780/635608 is probably more what OP is asking about

Comment: As a unary operator, `*` always comes before.  In the case of an abstract declarator it appears to come after because the item it acts on is implicit.  For instance, `(int *)` is an abstract declarator, but it's the same as `int *x` with the variable name `x` removed.

Comment: @pastaleg: there is a near infinite amount of C questions about pointers. Not all are identical.

Comment: @VeryNiceCoat: you should also look at the "right-left" rule:

http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html